# Finding relationship between columns of 2 SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

In my current environment there are hundreds of DB tables with 20% master tables. The values of some of the columns is a subset of a column from the master table. Unfortunately it is not documented.

Wondering if the master tables and dependent tables are known, how to craft a SQL statement to get which column of the dependent table is a subset of the master table column.

Thanks,
cabear

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Lets say there are 2 tables - one master table (mt) and one dependent tables (dt). Both could have 10 columns (c1.. c10). The dt column c5 values could be a subset of mt column c3. Would like to find out if any such relationship exists. Unfortunately there is no foreign key or anything defined in the current system.

Comment: That doesn't really help. Can you post the table structures and some data the represents the issue? That will help clarify what you are dealing with.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about querying the system catalog for metadata, particularly [for information about foreign key columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#_FAQ17).

Comment: Thanks.. went ahead and implemented using metadata and jdbc